# Vert.x-Config exception while reading properties file with comments

Tags: java, properties, vert.x

I'm new to vert.x and I'm trying to implement it in a new project at work.

I tried using the Vert.x-Config module in order to read a hierarchical .properties  file. For some reason I'm getting an exception from io.vertx.config.impl.ConfigRetrieverImpl ("Error while scanning configuration - ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1") when I'm trying to read a file with comments (starting with either # or ! as documented in .properties syntax) or with an blank lines.

Is this a bug in vertx-config or am I doing something wrong?

The code I'm using in order to read the file:

```
ConfigStoreOptions propertyWitHierarchical = new ConfigStoreOptions()
            .setFormat("properties")
            .setType("file")
            .setConfig(new JsonObject()
                    .put("path", "app.properties")
                    .put("hierarchical", true));
    ConfigRetrieverOptions options = new ConfigRetrieverOptions()
            .addStore(propertyWitHierarchical);
    ConfigRetriever configRetriever = ConfigRetriever.create(Vertx.vertx(), options);
```

The exception I'm getting:

```
io.vertx.config.impl.ConfigRetrieverImpl
SEVERE: Error while scanning configuration
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at io.vertx.config.impl.spi.PropertiesConfigProcessor$HierarchicalPropertiesReader.lambda$toJson$1(PropertiesConfigProcessor.java:122)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.reduce(ReferencePipeline.java:479)
    at io.vertx.config.impl.spi.PropertiesConfigProcessor$HierarchicalPropertiesReader.toJson(PropertiesConfigProcessor.java:130)
    at io.vertx.config.impl.spi.PropertiesConfigProcessor$HierarchicalPropertiesReader.readAsJson(PropertiesConfigProcessor.java:113)
    at io.vertx.config.impl.spi.PropertiesConfigProcessor.lambda$process$0(PropertiesConfigProcessor.java:70)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$2(ContextImpl.java:272)
    at io.vertx.core.impl.TaskQueue.run(TaskQueue.java:76)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

**Update #1**

This is an example of a properties file I used

```
# Server A address
serverA.addr=127.0.0.1

! Server A port
serverA.port=8080

# Server B address
serverB.addr=127.0.0.1

! Server B port
serverB.port=8080
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using vert.x-core 3.6.2 and vert.x-config 3.6.2

Comment: This should work fine. Could you post what your config files look like?

Comment: Please be aware that it only happens with a hierarchical properties file and not a flat file and that it was a bug in vertx-config.

Answer (score 1):

After investigating the vertx-config source code, I found the bug inside the PropertiesConfigProcessor class. It seems that the toJson method did not take care of comments and blank lines, so I've commited a bug fixe (waiting for approval) to the vertx-config project.

The fix was to add a filter to the stream api which should filter blank lines, and lines starting with either "#" or "!" (which is the correct syntax for comments in a properties files).